# Android: How to detect an untouch screen for 1 second while interacting?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am building an interactive game with native Android.
One of the feature I want, is to listen to touch events and to trigger some animation if the screen is left untouch for a given time: say one second.

My approach is to use a CountDownTimer in a ViewModel to measure the time before action.

It looks as follows:

```
private var _timeBeforeAction = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    // Countdown time
val timeBeforeAction: LiveData<Long> = _timeBeforeAction

val timerToAction = object : CountDownTimer(5*ONE_SECOND, ONE_SECOND) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        _timeBeforeAction.value = millisUntilFinished/ONE_SECOND
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
    }
}
```

The fragment feature a custom view listening to touch event:

```
if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {    
    // do things
}
if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    // do things
}
if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && pointerId==0){  
    binding.viewmodel!!.timerToAction.start()
    binding.viewmodel!!.timeBeforeAction.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                                timer ->
    if (timer==0L){
    // launch animation
    }
})
```

The problem is that whenever the event ACTION_UP is detected a new timer is launch in addition of timer launched at previous time, therefore the animation is launched multiple time.

I tried to replicate this behaviour with a simple button triggering the timer to start but in that case it did not show up.

In your opinion what is the best way to trigger an animation when the screen is left untouch for a given amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the simplest algorithm is:

1. Save the last touch time value (system time) when screen touched (on `ACTION_UP` event) and set "played once" to `false`.
2. On every frame/tick of your game loop or timer check passed time by subtracting last touch time from current system time.
3. If 1 second passed and "played once" flag is `false`, then launch animation and set "played once" flag to `true`.